# eWAM Allow Multiple Sessions

Tags: oop, ewam

The value of highlighted constant is “/MULTISESSION:”
I want to know from where this value is fetched for this parameter. Is there any specific config file I have to refer?

function AllowMultipleSessions return Boolean
    var curParam : CString

```
curParam = WF.GetParam(kw_MultipleSessions)
if curParam <> ''
   _Result = curParam = 'TRUE'
endIf
```

endFunc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the parameter "/MULTISESSION" is set in the config file “`MLRC.cfg`” which is located at “`[..]\Admin\RunningContext\MLRC.cfg`”.

"/MULTISESSION" is a command line parameter whose value can be supplied by a config file. The path of this config file is defined in the "Cmd line:" field of the running context(in Running Context catalog under "Run" tab).

Answer (score 0):

This (/MULTISESSION) process var needs to be set on the process's execution context:

1. eWEDRpc process (Param.ini file, referenced from WnetConf.ini file of the application server/WSM).
2. Process variable inside wNetConf.ini itself, under correct GSP process node.